# Sets that are not measurable in $\mathbb{R}.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Okay, so I am studying Measure Theory from Folland's *Real Analysis* book for the first time, and when he first defines measures, he gives 3 basic properties for it:

1. If $E_1, E_2, ...$ is a finite or infinite sequence of disjoint sets, then
   \begin{equation}
   l\left(\bigcup_i E_i\right)=\sum_i l(E_i)
   \end{equation}
2. If $E$ is congruent to $F$ (that is, if $E$ can be transformed into $F$ by translations, rotations, and reflections), then $l(E) = l(F)$.
3. $l(Q) = 1$, where $Q$ is the unit cube in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$

Then he goes on to show that these properties are inconsistent in the sense that you can find non-measurable sets in $\mathbb{R},$ more specifically, the interval $[0,1].$

He then constructs such a set $N$, which is basically the set which has exactly one element of all equivalence classes obtained by the equivalence relation $xRy$ iff $x-y \in \mathbb{Q}.$

I've read the proof, and I believe I understand it. The only problem is, this seems like a very counter-intuitive way to go about things. 
Shouldn't you actually start by defining what measure of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q^{c}}$ would be? And then just claim that measure of set $N$ is the same as measure of $\mathbb{Q^{c}},$ since they have the same cardinality? I'm assuming, of course, that we want measure to be related to cardinality in some sense.

Comment: measure and cardinality are only loosely related. The cantor set is an example for an uncountable set with measure 0.

Comment: $N$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb Q^c$, but this certainly doesn't mean that they have the same measure! For instance, all non-empty open intervals have the same cardinality, but they don't have the same measure.

Comment: I think the other two comments are excellent. Just a further note: I think you should not spend too much time on the issue now and read on. You will then see later on the significance of this counterexample.